# What is Chrome's Galaxy Fold responsive view based on?

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, samsung-galaxy

Our testers rely on Chrome's responsive view in dev tools to see how our site works with various devices. Recently, we've been getting some issues reported with the "galaxy fold" layout.

It appears that Chrome considers the Galaxy Fold to be a 280px wide screen. Which seems unusually narrow compared to most every other smartphone out there right now.

In googling this device, though, it appears the Fold actually as a screen of 1536x2152 which is, a bit larger than 280px. And even accounting for retina/virtual pixels, I can't see how 280 correlates to 1536.

Is Chrome just wrong here? Or is it maybe confused with some older Galaxy device with an unusually small screen?

Comment: https://developer.samsung.com/internet/blog/en-us/2020/01/27/current-web-on-galaxy-fold

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings oh...interesting! So, it appears you can get some ridiculously narrow layouts with the multi-window option on the fold (229!? Yikes). Looks like we need to do some super XXXS viewport options going forward. Yeesh.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the idea is that when the phone is folded, you should mostly get notifications and general info from the phone, and all view functionalities should be used with the phone unfolded. Because of that I believe in most cases the most appropriate way to deal with this situation is show a message to the user asking to unfold the phone in order to view the page. (Note that even the Galaxy Fold landing page doesn't display correctly when the phone is folded)

Comment: As [linked](https://r00t.io/managing-websites/a-way-to-fix-websites-for-samsung-galaxy-folds-280px-width-display/) in the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67733779/819417), a media rule can be used to display a "please unfold" div: `@media (max-width: 280px){ .unfold-notice { display: block !important; }}`